# Find out why scheduled oracle job stopped running

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

I have a job started by the scheduler which tracks its sub-steps in a JOB_LOG table. Since yesterday, 17 o'clock it stopped logging its activity. This could mean that the job encountered an error, or that it is really taking this long, but that is unlikely since the entire job with all sub-steps usually doesn't take more than 4 hours.

If I run `exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB ( job_name => 'RUN_JOB', force => true);` it tells me there is no job running. Just to be sure, I did an `exec dbms_scheduler.enable('RUN_JOB');` which did not give errors.

Looking at the job in SQL developer, I see the job is enabled and that is supposed to run every 15 minutes, but I don't see any output in the logging table indicating a new job has started.

How can I find out what the reason for the stopped logging and the non-running job is?
I could try to run the job by `exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('RUN_JOB');` but that would only obscure the actual error (assuming it works).

How can I look at the internal state of the job scheduler for this job? I would be especially interested in how the scheduler treats jobs that are still running (So that it doesn't start them every 15 minutes unless completed).

The output of `SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE JOB_NAME like 'RUN_%';` is `RUN_JOB SCHEDULED`;

The job has `RUN_COUNT` and `FAILURE_COUNT` of `12`.

More information: If I run `select JOB_NAME, STATUS, ERROR#, ADDITIONAL_INFO, ACTUAL_START_DATE from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where JOB_NAME like 'RUN_%' order by ACTUAL_START_DATE DESC;`
 I get error messages about `ORA-00001: unique constraint (RATOR_MONITORING.JOB_LOG_PK) violated`. This probably means there is an issue with the sequence generating the primary keys.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to locate the issue by calling:

```
select JOB_NAME, STATUS, ERROR#, ADDITIONAL_INFO, ACTUAL_START_DATE from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where JOB_NAME like 'RUN_%' order by ACTUAL_START_DATE DESC;
```

This was also helpful in seeing that the job was being run, but with errors:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE JOB_NAME like 'RUN_%';
```